# WCF REST based GET request returing raw XML

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest, silverlight-3.0

What I am trying to accomplish is adding a `GET` method to my WCF REST based service and accessing it via the `WebRequest` class from a Silverlight 3 client application.

I am getting the error **The remote server returned an error: NotFound.** which, as I understand it, can be just a generic error for any 500 error encountered on the server.

WCF operation contract:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "path/{id}")]
Stream Get(string id);
```

Operation implementation:

```
public Stream Get(string id)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";

    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<xml><id>1</id><name>Some Name</name></xml>));
}
```

Client code that throws exception:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://domain.com/my-service.svc/path/1");

webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
    x =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(x)) <--Exception thrown here
            using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
               //do stuff here...eventually.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    },
    null);
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the return type and have also tried returning `XmlElement` to no avail. I am really stumped here, any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Note that I can successfully hit the method via Fiddler and a web browser.

Comment: @rekire I'm using `WebHttpBinding`. Also, I do have a number of other methods working on this service definition but when creating a method with a return type of `Stream` or `XmlElement` that is when it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the code below into your web.config file(change the file name in the initializeData attribute appropriately.

If you are using full IIS, and not Casini or IIS Express (I use the latter), make sure to put the log file somewhere where your web application has write permissions).  This will cause WCF to generate a fairly detailed log file.  I've found the log to be pretty handy.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData= "c:\temp\WEBTraces.log" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I do not have direct access to the server that I am testing on so I could not read the log files. The service itself is SSL and is a claims based WIF service which makes it a little more complicated without access to the server.

Comment: +1 and I'm marking this as the correct answer, even though I had already had this configured but did not have the access to the servers to view the files until this morning. Sure enough, I got one of our admins to send me the logs and it indicated an exception. The exception was obscured because it was working locally...the exception was caused due to a missing certificate on one of the load balanced servers...of course I had installed the cert on my local machine and thus no problem there. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another thing to check:  Is domain.com exactly the same domain name as your silverlight app is running from (example -- is your SL app starting as localhost/xx and your web service call going to domain.com?

For security reasons, Silverlight will not make cross-domain web service calls unless the called domain grants it permission (same as Flash).  If this is the case, you will need a clientaccesspolicy.xml file.

You can read about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/12/12/silverlight-crossdomain-access-workarounds.aspx

There is a video here: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/introduction-to-data-and-networking/how-to-use-cross-domain-policy-files-with-silverlight

There are some helpers here: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx

Comment: Interesting. The Silverlight app is NOT running on the same server as the WCF service. However, currently I have a number of service methods functioning as expected within the same service. All the other methods return a serializable object. The problem only shows it's head when changing the return type to a `Stream` or `XmlElement`. Would you say that the way I have used `WebRequest` in combination with returning a `Stream` to a Silverlight app is correct outside of a possible security issue? Silverlight is not something I am strong in.

Comment: +1 for the helpful links, thanks. Still working on getting to the root of the problem but security could have something to do with it. I have tried adding both XML files but no go there.

Comment: @Craig I've never tried returning a stream.  We use WCF RIA Services for most of our Silverlight web service work.  I can tell you that silverlight only supports basic http bindings, so you can't use ws-* extensions.

Answer (score 0):

NotFound should mean 404 and not 500. A 404 error could be produced by a wrong URI.

```
Uri resturi = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}:8080/MyService/", hostname)); // http
WebHttpBinding rest = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly); // WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport for ssl
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), rest, resturi);
```

In the code example above your service would be aviable via `http://host:8080/MyService/path/1`

Comment: Correct, a NotFound is a 404 error but it sounds to me like you get a 500 when connecting via a Silverlight client for any 500 error being thrown on the server. Are you saying that this is not the case with Soilverlight? (I am no Silverlight developer). Regarding the URL, I can successfully access the the method via a web browser and Fiddler and I have copy and pasted the URL from where the client code is executed. I will update the question as you found a typo in the call to `CreateHttp`which is actually correct in the code. sorry. Any folow-up thoughts?